# как добавить атрибут unique для столбца после его создания? sql

Tags: sql

не могу найти как изменить или добавить атрибуты к столбцам, после их создание, то есть использовать ALTER TABLE но не могу найти продолжение к этому, какая команда для этого должна быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

команда:

`ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;`

пример:

`ALTER TABLE test_table MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE;`

Answer (score 3):

UNIQUE не есть атрибут столбца. Это всего лишь сокращённое указание на создание уникального индекса по этому столбцу.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f9021300477207559f49ae83ad9bf14)

Правильно:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `index_name` (`column_name`);
```

---

### UPDATE

> В разных СУБД синтаксис может отличаться. Например в Firebird будет `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT index_name UNIQUE (column_name)` – [Герман Борисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183614/%d0%93%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%91%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: В разных СУБД синтаксис может отличаться. Например в Firebird будет `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT index_name UNIQUE (column_name)`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Да, полная запись будет именно такой - любой уникальный индекс есть ограничение. Спасибо за дополнение.